# Optimize Dict values(List) Multiplication

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization, iteration, matrix-multiplication

I have Two dictionary elements as follows: Initial (25 key-Value pairs) Results (100 Key-Value Pairs)

```
Initial: {0: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],....... 24: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}

Results: {'0': [360, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 15, 0, 14, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 137, 21, 78, 65, 241, 31, 30, 88, 152, 3, 13, 67, 31, 145, 132, 37, 1, 107, 120, 171, 39, 35, 31, 8, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],......'100': [183, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 8, 1, 3, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 10, 25, 33, 121, 14, 6, 40, 62, 2, 5, 34, 23, 66, 61, 28, 1, 56, 46, 69, 23, 10, 14, 1, 13, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

In each iteration I multiply each value of Results dictionary to one value in Initial dictionary and call a function passing the product which will fetch me another value and I iterate this through the entire Initial dictionary  Values. I am doing this using below code:

```
for z in Initial.keys():
        for i in sorted(Results.keys()):
            result = {i :[x*y for x, y in zip(Initial[z], Results[i])]}
```

One complete cycle is taking about 1 minute and I will need to perform at least 5000 cycles to observe the final results. Any suggestions on improving the performance/Optimization of code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are lists and therefore you have to multiply one element at a time. You can cast your values (lists) to arrays first and then use vectorized multiplication thereby removing the use of list comprehension and element wise multiplication as follows

```
# Converting the values to arrays once for all
Initial = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in Initial.items()}
Results = {k:np.array(v) for k,v in Results.items()}

# Now just using vectorized multipliction
for z in Initial.keys():
    for i in sorted(Results.keys()):
        result = {i :Initial[z] * Results[i]}
```

Since you did not provide complete data, I tried your code for some 1 million iterations and found the vectorized code much faster. Try it out on your original data and see if you get a speed up (which you should).

---

**Test case for comparing times**

Your **list comprehension** version took 1 minute 6 seconds

```
for ii in range(500000):
    for z in Initial.keys():
        for i in sorted(Results.keys()):
            result = {i :[x*y for x, y in zip(Initial[z], Results[i])]}
```

The following **vectorized** operation took 2.9 seconds

```
for ii in range(500000):
    for z in Initial.keys():
        for i in sorted(Results.keys()):
            result = {i :Initial[z] * Results[i]}
```

Comment: I definitely see an improvement, but I have another problem now. I am using 'i' and result[i] to pass on to my next function and I am unable to change the format in which they are generated. every element in the list result[i] is enclosed with array() and every element in list of 'i' is enclosed with array() and contains dtype='|s10' as an extra element. Any inputs on how to go about this?

Comment: You can try converting back the elements from array to list using list(element)

Comment: How do we split each value in an np.array() with a '.'?

Comment: Please add some sample array you want to split in the comment. I will reply in the morning.

Comment: Got something like this:
[[253   0   2 ...   0   0   0]
 [150   0   0 ...   0   0   0]]

But need something like
[[253.   0.   2. ...   0.   0.   0.]
 [150.   0.   0. ...   0.   0.   0.]]

Comment: If this is element, then you can use list(element[0]) and list(element[1])

Comment: No, I mean this is just a piece of it. There will be atleast 25X100 such records, so if there is a way we can do it while we generate that'd be better

Comment: Ok let's say `x = np.array([[253, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0], [150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] )`, the you can convert using `x = [list(map(float, i)) for i in x]`

Comment: Your efforts were extremely helpful, Thank you so much!

Comment: @Prabhanjan: How much time one cycle is taking now as compared to one minute previously?

Comment: I have not measured it yet, fixing some other stuffs before I can actually test it. I will post it here once I do it.

Comment: Great. Glad to help :)

Comment: I am trying to store all the result[i] in a list like this:
X = []
x.append(list(result[i]))

Gives me the following error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
Can you please tell me on how to go about this?

Comment: You are using small x for appending but your list is capital X. Use X.append( )...... small x is still an array... got it? Python is case sensitive

Comment: I am using a Large X in real, that was a typo here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183087/discussion-between-prabhanjan-and-bazingaa).